# combining video files with AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetwriter, avassetreader

I'm attempting to combine a number of video files into a single file with specific codec settings. I used to use the `AVAssetExportSession` for this, but I now need more control over the codec than the `AVAssetExportSession` offers.

Below I've posted the `createFinalVideo:` function that handles the combination of the video files.

The approach I've taken is attempting to write to the same file with an `AVAssetWriter` while simply starting the session at the location where the next video should be appended. I know this will not work because the `AVAssetWriter` apparently doesn't allow for this behavior.

Previously, I had the `AVAssetWriter` defined outside of the for loop, and I was attempting to add a new input for each video file (each pass of the for loop). However, it appears that `AVAssetWriter` doesn't allow for adding new inputs after `[AVAssetWriter startWriting]` has been called.

My question is how do I do what I'm trying to do the right way?

```
/**
 * Final video creation. Merges audio-only and video-only files.
 **/
-(void)createFinalVideo:(id)args
{
    ENSURE_SINGLE_ARG(args, NSDictionary);

    // presentation id
    NSString * presID = [args objectForKey:@"presID"];

    // array of video paths
    NSArray * videoPathsArray = [args objectForKey:@"videoPaths"];

    videoSuccessCallback = [args objectForKey:@"videoSuccess"];
    videoCancelCallback  = [args objectForKey:@"videoCancel"];
    videoErrorCallback   = [args objectForKey:@"videoError"];

    NSError * error = nil;

    NSFileManager * fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString * bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    /*********************************************************************/
    /* BEGIN: merge all videos into a final MP4 */
    /*********************************************************************/

    // create the final video output file as MP4 file
    NSString * finalOutputFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/final_video.mp4", documentsDirectory, presID];
    NSURL * finalOutputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalOutputFilePath];

    // delete file if it exists
    if ([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:finalOutputFilePath]) {
        [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:finalOutputFilePath error:nil];
    }

    float renderWidth = 640, renderHeight = 480;

    NSDictionary *videoCleanApertureSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:renderWidth], AVVideoCleanApertureWidthKey,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:renderHeight], AVVideoCleanApertureHeightKey,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureHorizontalOffsetKey,
                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], AVVideoCleanApertureVerticalOffsetKey,
                                                nil];

    NSDictionary *codecSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:1960000], AVVideoAverageBitRateKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:24],AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey,
                                   videoCleanApertureSettings, AVVideoCleanApertureKey,
                                   AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline30, AVVideoProfileLevelKey,
                                   nil];

    NSDictionary *videoCompressionSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                              codecSettings,AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:renderWidth], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:renderHeight], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                              AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspect, AVVideoScalingModeKey,
                                              nil];

    NSError *aerror = nil;

    // next start time for adding to the compositions
    CMTime nextStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

    // loop through the video paths and add videos to the composition
    for (NSString * path in videoPathsArray) {
        // wait for each video to finish writing before continuing
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        // create video writer
        AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:finalOutputFileUrl fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:nil];
        NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

        NSLog(@"at the top of the for loop");
        NSLog(@"%@", path);

        AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                                assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                outputSettings:videoCompressionSettings];
        NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
        NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
        videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
        [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

        AVAssetWriterInput* audioWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                                assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                outputSettings:nil];
        NSParameterAssert(audioWriterInput);
        NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]);
        audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;
        [videoWriter addInput:audioWriterInput];

        [videoWriter startWriting];

        // video setup
        AVAsset *avAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:nil];
        AVAssetReader *reader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset error:&aerror];
        AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]objectAtIndex:0];

        CMTime videoDuration = avAsset.duration;
        // Wait until the duration is actually available
        int durationAttempts = 5;
        while(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration) == 0 && durationAttempts > 0) {
            durationAttempts--;
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.3];
            videoDuration = avAsset.duration;
        }
        NSLog(@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS video duration in secs: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration));

        //videoWriterInput.transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform;
        NSDictionary *videoOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
        AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *asset_reader_output = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:videoOptions];
        [reader addOutput:asset_reader_output];

        //audio setup
        AVAssetReader *audioReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:avAsset error:nil];
        AVAssetTrack* audioTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
        AVAssetReaderOutput *readerOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:audioTrack outputSettings:nil];
        [audioReader addOutput:readerOutput];

        NSLog(@"startSessionAtSourceTime: %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(nextStartTime));
        [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:nextStartTime];
        // set next start time
        nextStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextStartTime, videoDuration);
        [reader startReading];

        dispatch_queue_t _processingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AVAssetWriterQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        [videoWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:_processingQueue usingBlock:^{
            while ([videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
                CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;
                if ([reader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading &&
                    (sampleBuffer = [asset_reader_output copyNextSampleBuffer])) {

                    BOOL result = [videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

                    if (!result) {
                        [reader cancelReading];
                        NSLog(@"NO RESULT");
                        NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetWriterInputStatusFailed: %@", videoWriter.error);
                        if (videoErrorCallback != nil) {
                            [self _fireEventToListener:@"videoError" withObject:nil listener:videoErrorCallback thisObject:nil];
                        }
                        return;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];

                    switch ([reader status]) {
                        case AVAssetReaderStatusReading:
                            // the reader has more for other tracks, even if this one is done
                            break;

                        case AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted:
                            [audioReader startReading];
                            [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:nextStartTime];
                            NSLog(@"Request");
                            NSLog(@"Asset Writer ready :%d", audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData);
                            while (audioWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
                                CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer;
                                if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading && (nextBuffer = [readerOutput copyNextSampleBuffer])) {
                                    NSLog(@"Ready");
                                    if (nextBuffer) {
                                        NSLog(@"NextBuffer");
                                        [audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:nextBuffer];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    [audioWriterInput markAsFinished];

                                    //dictionary to hold duration
                                    if ([audioReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted) {
                                        NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted");
                                        [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
                                            switch([videoWriter status]) {
                                                case AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted:
                                                    NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted");
                                                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                                                    break;

                                                case AVAssetWriterStatusCancelled:
                                                    NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetWriterStatusCancelled");
                                                    if (videoSuccessCallback != nil) {
                                                        [self _fireEventToListener:@"videoCancel" withObject:nil listener:videoCancelCallback thisObject:nil];
                                                    }
                                                    return;
                                                    break;

                                                case AVAssetWriterStatusFailed:
                                                    NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetWriterStatusFailed");
                                                    if (videoSuccessCallback != nil) {
                                                        [self _fireEventToListener:@"videoError" withObject:nil listener:videoErrorCallback thisObject:nil];
                                                    }
                                                    return;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case AVAssetReaderStatusFailed:
                            NSLog (@"[INFO] MODULE-VIDUTILS createFinalVideo AVAssetReaderStatusFailed, @%", reader.error);
                            if (videoSuccessCallback != nil) {
                                [self _fireEventToListener:@"videoError" withObject:nil listener:videoErrorCallback thisObject:nil];
                            }
                            [videoWriter cancelWriting];
                            return;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }];
        // wait for the writing to finish
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        NSLog(@"Write Ended");
    }
    NSLog(@"got here -- should have waited for all videos to complete first");

    // call success if we got here
    if (videoSuccessCallback != nil) {
        [self _fireEventToListener:@"videoSuccess" withObject:nil listener:videoSuccessCallback thisObject:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a replacement for `AVAssetExportSession` called [`SDAVAssetExportSession`](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) that allows you to specify settings instead of using presets.